# ispossible create websocket server connected to another websocket?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, websocket

I need WebSocket code for implement structure of my client. I will create WebSocket server for my client with receive by client from ex: binance websocket

Just part of connect to binance websocket need implement.

ASP.NET Core 5 C#

```cs
private async Task Echo(HttpContext context, WebSocket webSocket)
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
    WebSocketReceiveResult result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
    while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
    {
        await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count), result.MessageType, result.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);

        result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
    }
    await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Comment: we need to see a fully reproducible example and the error you are getting

Comment: this is my code in setup basic send message on websocket just i need make sure we can connect websocket server to another one ? and my client recieve master websocket 
WS A > WS B > Client

Answer (score 1):

I did something like that. I created 2 WebSocket servers, one acting as a proxy to the other. You can check it out, maybe it works for you or at least you can find some answers there. It is a bit disordered because I did it as a research, so ask me if you need more info.

https://github.com/RenanDiaz/WebSockets

```
public override async Task OnConnected(WebSocket socket)
{
    await base.OnConnected(socket);
    if (_client == null)
    {
        _client = new ClientWebSocket();
        await _client.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://localhost:5001/chat"), CancellationToken.None);
        var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveMessageFromAPIServer));
        thread.Start();
    }
}

private async void ReceiveMessageFromAPIServer()
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
    while (_client != null)
    {
        var result = await _client.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
        if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
        {
            await _client.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "", CancellationToken.None);
            break;
        }
        var messageString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count);
        var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IncomingAPIServerMessage>(messageString);
        await SendMessageToAll(message);
    }
}
```